# What this kernel code is getting corrupted?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Here is the code section producing an Oops

```
stuff = vmalloc(10);
if (stuff == NULL) {
    printk("\n Could not allocate memory chunk\n");
} else {
    printk("\n Successfully allocated memory chunk\n");
}
/* Oops here */
```

---

```
Successfully allocate memory chunk..------------[ cut here ]------------..
WARNING: at mm/slub.c:2929 ksize+0x43/0x7a()..
Hardware name: VMware Virtual Platform..
Pid: 21893, comm: insmod Tainted: G..W  2.6.33.3-85.fc13.i686.PAE #1..
Call Trace:[<c043d625>] warn_slowpath_common+0x65/0x7c[<c04c7a1f>] ? 
ksize+0x43/0x7a[<c043d649>]..warn_slowpath_null+0xd/0x10..
[<c04c7a1f>] ksize+0x43/0x7a..[<d0e6229d>] xt_gtpu_init+0x29d/0x2d1 [xt_SGW_GTPU].. 
[<d0e62000>] ? xt_gtpu_init+0x0/0x2d1 [xt_SGW_GTPU]..[<c0403051>] 
do_one_initcall+0x4c/0x13a..[<c0466623>]..sys_init_module+0xa7/0x1dc..
[<c040885f>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28..---[ end trace e82ed3faa2bc068a ]---..
I got: 4096 bytes of memory
```

Comment: code is added in module init

Comment: that is just a printk..

Comment: @kernelCoder It'll be pretty impossibly for us to diagnose the problem without seeing the source code.

Comment: stuff = vmalloc(10);
    if(stuff == NULL)
    {
         printk("\n Can not allocate memory chunk\n");
    }
    printk("\n Successfully allocate memory chunk\n");

Comment: @kernelCoder, Can you please put the code in the question and not as a comment?

Comment: The error happens _after_ the code you posted has run... We can't guess. (Also please at least attempt to format your code readably.)

Comment: Try not to allocate 10 but PAGE_SIZE at least?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give you some clues to understand what the Kernel is telling you.
What you are seeing is a Kernel warning but what is it ?

Some Kernel code expects specific conditions to run correctly. If the user (i.e. you) does not fulfil the required conditions, the code can react in two ways :

- It can correct it but will produce a whiny message : the **Warning**. Such code segments will be characterized by the use of the `WARN_ON(my_condition)` macro.
- It won't correct it but it cannot go further : it will produce an Oops that will crash your Kernel using the macro `BUG_ON(my_buggy_condition)`

Your case hit the first item (lucky you ;) ). The macro will dump some information about what context is surrounding the warning. Let's decrypt it.

`WARNING: at mm/slub.c:2929 ksize+0x43/0x7a()..` says clearly that the `WARN_ON` macro was hit on the line 2929 of the mm/slub.c file, in the function `ksize()`. And, miracle if you browse this file (see Ilya's answer), on line 2929 here is : `WARN_ON(!PageCompound(page));`.
With the remaining call stack displayed, you can identify the entry point that lead to such a warning. In your case, it seems like you are passing something wrong to the `xt_gtpu_init()` function.

I can't tell you more since you did not expose your `xt_gtpu_init()` call, but it looks like some allocation flags are not correctly set ([here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/page-flags.h#L345) is the definition of the `PageCompound()` function).

That is not an issue, but a last remark : `vmalloc()` function expects you to provide a size which is a multiple of `PAGE_SIZE`. If you do not, it should round up the requested length to the closest `PAGE_SIZE` multiple. That is why, I suppose, you get the `I got: 4096 bytes of memory` statement later on.